# How do you turn on/off the tact light or laser sight in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've killed more people coming down the subway tunnel than any other spot because I can see the tact light coming down the tunnel.  Likewise, I have been killed more than I have killed using the tact light.  While I'm still learning how to best use the light, **it would be nice if I can turn the stupid thing on and off**.  Anybody know how?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you have not modified any of the key mappings, you can toggle the light and laser off and on using <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

On the Xbox the light is controlled by the D-Pad.

Comment: Up, specifically. Down will select firing mode.

Comment: Didn't know that. I refuse to use it anyway as it's a cheap as hell attachment. But, hey, good to know if I pick up someone's gun that uses cheap as hell attachments. =)

Answer (score 3):

On PS3 you do this with the `UP` button on the directional buttons (seems to be the same on XBox)

Answer (score 0):

UP on the D-pad will toggle light/laser on/off and DOWN selects firing mode (single/burst/full).

Comment: Hi, @Jamie Simpson, welcome to Arquade. Try avoiding to re-word earlier answers. If an answer already has the information you are trying to add, simply edit the earlier answer.